What cannot be bought and sold, according to Thomist Catholic moral theologians?
What cannot licitly be bought and sold, according to Thomist Catholic moral theologians?
(I know buying/selling relics is forbidden.)

Down-voters, please explain your down-votes.

The following cannot be bought/sold:

Nonexistent things

This occurs with the sin of usury.
Summa Theologica II-II q. 78 a. 1 ("Whether it is a sin to take usury for money lent?") c.: "To take usury for money lent is unjust in itself, because this is to sell what does not exist."


Spiritual goods

This is the sin of simony.


[Spiritual?] Health

Alfonso de Castro, O.F.M., Against All Heresies, § Simony: "Giezi, the servant of the prophet Eliseus, was struck with perpetual leprosy by God, because he accepted money for the benefit of [spiritual?] healing which Eliseus had conferred upon Naaman the leper. [4 Kings 5:27]"


Relics

1917 Code of Canon Law canon 1289: "It is nefarious to sell sacred relics" (cf. 1983 CIC 1190).



This list is by no means comprehensive.

+1 Quick question: Is this a complete list to the best of your knowledge? I ask, because your question says "all."

@DDS I've changed it to asking what cannot be bought/sold.

@DDS No, it's not complete. Presumably human bodies (as in chattel-slavery) or body parts cannot be bought/sold, but I'm still looking for a reference for that.

Arguably, anything which could only be used for an immoral purpose since to do so would be participation in another's sin (which is a sin)
